# Using CQLSSTableWriter concurrently

Tags: multithreading, cassandra, bulkinsert, apache-spark

I'm trying to create Cassandra SSTables from the results of a batch computation in Spark. Ideally, each partition should create the SSTable for the data it holds in order to parallelize the process as much as possible (and probably even stream it to the Cassandra ring as well)

After the initial hurdles with the `CQLSSTableWriter` (like requiring the yaml file), I'm confronted now with this issue:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempting to load already loaded column family customer.rawts
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.load(Schema.java:347)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.load(Schema.java:112)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CQLSSTableWriter$Builder.forTable(CQLSSTableWriter.java:336)
```

I'm creating a writer on each parallel partition like this:

```
def store(rdd:RDD[Message]) = {
    rdd.foreachPartition( msgIterator => {
      val writer = CQLSSTableWriter.builder()
        .inDirectory("/tmp/cass")
        .forTable(schema)
        .using(insertSttmt).build()
      msgIterator.foreach(msg => {...})
    })}
```

And if I'm reading the exception correctly, I can only create one writer per table in one JVM. I guess writings to the `writer` will not be thread-safe and even if they were the contention that multiple threads will create by having all parallel tasks trying to dump few GB of data to disk at the same time will defeat the purpose of using the SSTables for bulk upload anyway.

So, are there ways to use the `CQLSSTableWriter` concurrently?

If not, what is the next best option to load batch data at high throughput in Cassandra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have observed, a single writer can only be used in serial (ConcurrentModificationExceptions will happen if you do not), and creating multiple writers in the JVM fails due to static schema construction within the Cassandra code that the SSTableWriter uses.

I'm not aware of any workaround other than to spawn multiple JVMs, each writing to a separate directory.

We have filed a Cassandra JIRA ticket to address this issue.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7463

Comment: What would you recommend to do batch loading into Cassandra?